# With PHP, how can I split a string into an array where the delimiters are a variable string enclosed with braces like '[Ab]'

Tags: php, string, explode, preg-split

Using PHP, How can I split the following string "Random words [Ab]another few words here [Bx]and yet a [Sq4]few more" into the following array:

```
 array[0] = 'Random words ' 
 array[1] = '[Ab]'
 array[2] = 'another few words here ' 
 array[3] = '[Bx]' 
 array[4] = 'and yet a ' 
 array[5] = '[Sq4]' 
 array[6] = 'few more'
```

where the String [xxx] acts as the delimiter and there can be 1-4 alpha numeric characters inbetween the braces?

Also how would I do something similar where I create two arrays:

```
arrayA[0] = 'Random words '
arrayA[1] = 'another few words here '
arrayA[2] = 'and yet a '
arrayA[3] = 'few more'

arrayB[0] = '[Ab]'
arrayB[1] = '[Bx]'
arrayB[2] = '[Sq4]'
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern with *preg_split*

```
$pattern = '~(?=\[[^]]*])|]\K(?=[^[])~';
```

or more simple:

```
$pattern = '~(?=\[)|]\K(?=[^[])~';
```

or:

```
$pattern = '~(?=\[)|(?<=])~';
```

Comment: I tried that and ended up with: 

Array
(
    [0] => Random words 
    [1] => [Ab]another few words here 
    [2] => [Bx]and yet a 
    [3] => [Sq4]few more
)

Comment: @dnpage: retry with the new pattern

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte
Nice! Array
(
    [0] => Random words 
    [1] => [Ab]
    [2] => another few words here 
    [3] => [Bx]
    [4] => and yet a 
    [5] => [Sq4]
    [6] => few more
)
and from there I can loop through the array and pick out the ones that begin with '[' to make my 2 arrays.
I really do need to study regular expressions and see how you built that pattern.  Thanks for your help!